# Can't resolve github Dependabot alert

Tags: github, dependabot

I got this security notification:

```
Remediation
Upgrade node-fetch to version 2.6.1 or later. For example:

node-fetch@^2.6.1:
  version "2.6.1"
```

But this error has occurred.  : `Dependabot cannot create a pull request as one or more other dependencies require a version that is incompatible with this update.`

Also, I did `yarn upgrade` But Nothing has changed.

What is this ?? How Can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have seen this issue multiple times myself, and it is well discussed in [here](https://github.com/dependabot/feedback/issues/578) and [here](https://github.com/dependabot/dependabot-core/issues/2327).

If you are using `npm`, you can try with `npm audit fix`. If you using `yarn`, give `yarn upgrade --latest` a shot.

Comment: It disappeared as I kept updating the code. thanks.